# c++ network credentials

Tags: c++, mfc, credentials

I have web service in my MFC Application and I want to write something like:

WebService * ws = new WebService();
 ws->Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(user, pass);

I could not find Credentials class in MFC. Is there such class in MFC?

Answer (score 1):

MFC does not have a NetworkCredential class, but if you use .Net (CLR), then you can find [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) in the System.Net namespace (link is to a pertinent MSDN article).